# Azure VM ping and telnet not working

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, telnet

I have an azure VM (resource manager) on the new portal running windows server 2012 r2 with HPC with a public IP, Currently i can login to the VM using a remote desktop client but i cannot ping myself (public ip) when logged in or ping form my local computer.

I also want to telnet on the VM to another server but always fail saying "couldnot connect to host on ip_here on port 8310"

Currently, I have enabled port 80 on the inbound security rules of my VM in azure portal and added a new rule to allow port 80 on my VM, I have also added a telnet client and server windows feature on my VM and started the service.

Still telnet and ping are not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ping Azure VMs.

You can try this tool instead, as detailed on the url below

```
psping CLJun21WS12R2A.cloudapp.net:56972
```

You can see alternatives here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity.aspx

Comment: how about telnet?

Comment: Is this of any help? http://serverfault.com/questions/627776/no-ping-telnet-connection-between-vm